# Drupal 7 Views filter between start and end date

Tags: views, datetime

I try to accomplish the following:

I want to create a View, which is automatically listing the newest terms.

There a two terms a year (summer term 01.04.-30.09) and (winter term 01.10-31.03).

Those terms have several Events in it. So i tried to filter them automatically with a reference of "now"

So i set the filters as the following:

start-date is greater than or equal to "now"

end-date is less than of equal to "now"

I also tried to switch the arguments,

just as explained in this article: [Drupal 7 Views filter between two dates](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36380/drupal-7-views-filter-between-two-dates)?

but it didn't do anything.

I made some screenshots, to show you how i configured the view and the event.

[image: start-date-argument]
[image: end-date-argument]
[image: date-configuration]
[image]

(And yes, the other filter criteria s are met.^^)

I hope you can help me with this problem, or tell me another trick to accomplish my goal.

Comment: Not an really objectively comment, but i accidently deleted the greetings, so hi everyone^^

Comment: Hello and welcome. Greetings are casually edited out of the questions and answers. This site is not a forum, so deleting them was a good move. Comment, on the other hand, is more acceptable, as comments are second-class citizens here. Just don't get upset if / when your comments will get deleted ;)

Comment: are dates on the term or on the node ?

Comment: Ok, there is nothing wrong, i made a big mistake by myself -.-,
I watched over everything carefully, but not over the fact, that the current date is far away from the start date. I thought it would fit, cause the foregoing page has the winter term already in it. But they havent done it automatically but manually.
Anyway,sorry for the trouble and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there is nothing wrong, i made a big mistake by myself -.-, I watched over everything carefully, but not over the fact, that the current date is far away from the start date. I thought it would fit, cause the foregoing page has the winter term already in it. But they havent done it automatically but manually. Anyway,sorry for the trouble and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This module should do exactly what you need: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_between_dates_filter

Comment: when suggesting a module, please include a description of what the module does and (where applicable) how it would answer the question